# sudo open -e ~/.bash_profile Permission denied mac

Tags: macos, path, permissions, sudo, bash

I am trying to edit bash_profile file to add path to my sdk through the following command on my mac machine.
sudo touch ~/.bash_profile; open -e ~/.bash_profile

It opens the file in TextEdit but does not allow me to edit it. Though i have given super-user permission and password while running the above command. It is giving me following message when i try to edit it.

"You don’t own the file “.bash_profile” and don’t have permission to write to it.
You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate. Only the duplicate will include your changes."
I am new to mac. So please elaborate your answers.

Comment: By the way, you should not create the file as the super-user, The `~/` path is your own home directory, and the `~/.bash_profile` file should be owned by you.

Comment: I am not trying to create this file. It already exists. I am just trying to edit it to set a PATH variable.

Comment: Then why the `touch` command? And it seems that your user is not the owner of the file. If you do e.g. `ls -l ~/.bash_profile` what user does it list? And `sudo open -e ~/.bash_profile` doesn't work either (it should!)?

Comment: ls -l ~/.bash_profile shows following :  -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  104 Jan 21 17:26 /Users/farheen/.bash_profile

Comment: And sudo open -e ~/.bash_profile gives the sme permission denied error

Comment: The OSX `open` command may change user or something. As for the file, it should be owned by you (`farheen`). Change it using `chown`: `sudo chown farheen ~/.bash_profile`. After that you should not need to use `sudo` to edit it (just use the `open` command!, don't do `sudo touch`!).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  It would be great if u can post above as an answer so that i can accept the answer !

Comment: Updated my existing answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that the file isn't owned by your user, but by `root`. You need to change the owner of the file to your user, then you can open and edit the file without the use of `sudo`:

```
sudo chown farheen ~/.bash_profile
```

This will, as the super-user, change the owner of the file back to you.

Comment: sudo open -e ~/.bash_profile; I did this still i get the same error message. All i want to do is edit this file.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac User Catalina,

`.bash_profile` not open, they need grant permission to edit this file. You can achieve by below steps

1) Open the terminal and enter below command ex: `sudo chown iMac ~/.bash_profile`

```
sudo chown {your username} ~/.bash_profile
```

2) Open editor in the terminal, here i used `nano`

```
nano .bash_profile
```

3) Edit your text you want.

4) To save the changes you've made, press `Ctrl + O`

5) To exit nano, press `Ctrl + X`

6) And finally to load your changes, enter below command

```
source .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

OR

You can give permission and make it executable file using like below:

That error likely means that '**bash_profile**' isn't executable. If it's in the current directory, you can make it executable with **chmod +x bash_profile**.