# VS code, output is not showing

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I installed vs code, python and git bash. I integrated everything.
while printing anything, it's showing PERMISSION DENIED in terminal. Can anyone help how to execute the code.

Comment: It is extremely helpful to provide more detail and give people things to work with to help you. Examples of the output. Of the commands. Whatever. [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you need to give yourself permission to execute the file.

Refer to this post: [sudo open -e ~/.bash_profile Permission denied mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065542/sudo-open-e-bash-profile-permission-denied-mac)

Hope this helps